# Joomla 1.6 Upgrade from 1.5

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.6

http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_multiple_item_select_list_parameter_type

Thats the documentation for the way to add a custom parameter type to your module and if you look at the bottom round there is this line : ***Saving parameter values to a database***

Please can someone tell me if there is any documentation on how to do this in Joomla 1.6 because I cannot find it anywhere?

I understand completely how this works though, You need to bind your custom options (example: the list selection from a multiple selection input box) to the parent so that it will be able to save the selection to the DB.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT added code

```
protected function getInput()
    {

        $options = array();
        $attr = '';

        $attr .= ' multiple="multiple"';
        $attr .= ' style="width:220px;height:160px;"';

        // Get the database instance
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        // Build the select query
        $query = 'SELECT params FROM jos_modules'
            . ' WHERE module="mod_pmailer_subscription"';
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $params = $db->loadObjectList();

        // Decode the options to get thje api key and url
        $options = json_decode($params[0]->params, true);

        // Create a new API utility class
        $api = new PMailerSubscriptionApiV1_0(
            $options['enterprise_url'],
            $options['pmailer_api_key']
        );

        // Get the lists needed for subscription
        $response = $api->getLists();

        // Make a default entry for the dropdown
        $lists = array('0' => 'Please select a list');

        // Builds the options for the dropdown
        foreach ( $response['data'] as $list )
        {
            $lists[$list['list_id']]['id']    = $list['list_id'];
            $lists[$list['list_id']]['title'] = $list['list_name'];
        }

        // The dropdown output
        return JHTML::_(
            'select.genericlist',
            $lists,
            'jform[params][list_id]',
            trim($attr),
            'id',
            'title',
            $options['list_id']
        );

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_1.6#Converting_your_JParameters_to_JForms), How to convert JParams to JForm

EDIT :

I checked the forum and found that you are using

```
// Builds the options for the dropdown
foreach ( $response['data'] as $list )
{
   $lists[$list['list_id']] = $list['list_name'];
}
```

but in JHTML you are passing id and title for text and value field,

Use

```
    // Builds the options for the dropdown
    foreach ( $response['data'] as $list )
    {
        $lists[$list['list_id']]['id']    = $list['list_id'];
        $lists[$list['list_id']]['title'] = $list['list_name'];
    }
```

Comment: Its interesting I have looked at this documentation already but There is no real example of how the getInput() needs to be implemented: "replace function fetchElement($name, $value, &$node, $control_name) with protected function getInput()"

Comment: Did you try the 1.5 element code in 1.6. I did that without any problem.

Comment: `Then you still need to replace the references to $control_name and others in your new JForm field, but at least the bulk of the work has been done automatically` Are you talking about this? The parent class JFormField has a protected variable called `protected $formControl;`

Comment: @etbal : let me know what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I have implemented it and it still does not save the selection into the module params field though. I will edit my question and add the code now

Comment: I think its because I do not populate the multiple select box with `select.option` objects.